# JSON parsing with Ruby and learning to hate "Ã¢"

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to parse some JSON from readability, and I am not having the expected result when I hit UTF-8 encoded characters:

```
require "json"               #require "json/pure" No joy
myInput='["\u201c valid utf8\u201d from a sample."]'

json=JSON.parse(myInput)

puts "|#{json}|"        # => |["Ã¢alid utf8Ã¢               (cntl chars as well)
```

My naive expectations is that `#{json}` and `#{myInput}` would be "similar."

I've searched, read, and experimented for sometime. I expect my head to hit the desk when I find out what I am missing.

How can I parse the JSON to avoid the `Ã` and control characters?

---

**My issue is solved:**

When having encoding issues always make sure to check your TERMINAL'S encoding.

Putty's default character setting is wonderful Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).

Thank you Neil Slater for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This works fine for me. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Behaviour may also vary according to terminal you are using. If Ruby thinks it is good to output UTF-8 encoded text, but your terminal is displaying ISO-8859-1, then you may see odd output. I get `|“ valid utf8” from a sample.|` in Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: If I set my terminal to ISO-8859-1, then I get `|ÔÇ£ valid utf8ÔÇØ from a sample.|` so not the same as you , but does show this could be an issue.

Comment: I was right.

My head hit desk.

I knew it was LATIN1 which is the default for Putty.

Set to UTF-8 as god intended and everyone is happy.

Thanks for your help, and I never considered that it could be my putty window.

Comment: Back when PCs, Windows and Putty were first developed, ISO-8859-1, WIN-1252 and their ilk were supposed to be sufficient for mankind's needs for eternity. Then someone pointed out that the world isn't U.S. *OR* Microsoft *OR* IBM centric, and other languages *DO* exist. Thus UTF-8 and UNICODE were invented. At that point we (developers and computer people) should have started using UTF-8, but NOOoooo, some still default to that old way of thinking, which causes all sorts of problems for support staff daily. I'm glad you saw the light. :-)

Comment: And wait until you receive XML documents that are *supposed* to be UTF-8 but some maroon decided to directly enter ISO-8859-n characters using ALT + the numeric keypad. Your XML parser will get really mad, and some will explode in flames.